# Flutter navigation with api

Tags: api, flutter

I created an app which gets the data from API then shows that in another page.
in the emulator, I don't have any problems, and the app runs without any error, but in my phone app standing on a first page which shows loading and doesn't navigate to my destination.
here is my code I don't know why is this happening.
Please answer if you find anything.

```
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    NetworkHelper networkHelper =
        NetworkHelper('https://fortniteapi.io/shop?lang=en');

    var itemData = await networkHelper.getData();

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return myItemsScreen(itemData: itemData,);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
      body: Center(
        child: SpinKitDoubleBounce(
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 50.0
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check for any errors in debug console while running on phone?

Comment: Could you please share the error message from the logs?

Comment: While in the phone app that is if you are using build apk or any build function did you add internet permissions ?

Comment: No i don't add internet premission :)